# Как из "Привет" получить "ирП"?

Tags: python

Типа так я пробовал

```
s="Привет"
s[:3:-1]
```

Но мне нужен именно срез из перевернутого слова

Answer (score 3):

**вариант 1:**

```
s[::-1][-3:]
```

сначала перевернули, потом срезали

**вариант 2:**

```
s[2::-1]
```

или

```
s[-4::-1]
```

срезали и перевернули одновременно

вариант 3:

```
s[:3][::-1]
```

сначала срезали, потом перевернули

Answer (score 0):

Немного регулярок:

```
import re

s = "Привет"

m = re.search('(.)(.)(.)', s)
print(m[3]+m[2]+m[1])
# ирП

print(''.join(m.groups()[::-1]))
# ирП

print(re.search('(...)', s)[1][::-1])
# ирП
```